WhenAll Stuck in Blazor WASM
I have next code in Blazor Page. It is calling in OnParametrSetAsync(). i used only async await. No Task.Wait() or Task.Result.
   private async Task SelectNewAddress(AddressElement elem, bool withFillParam)
  {


          foreach (var fieldSource in elem.DicFields.Values)
          {
              if (fieldSource.Id > 0)
                  address.SelectAddressField(fieldSource);
          }

          var lowLevelElementKey = address.DicFields.Where(p => p.Value != null && p.Value.Id > 0).Max(p => p.Key);

          List<Task> listTasks = new List<Task>();

          if (withFillParam)
          {
              var t = FillParams();
              listTasks.Add(t);
          }

          foreach (var kkey in address.DicFields.Keys)
          {
              var field = address.DicFields[kkey];

              if (field.Id > 0 && field.IdParent > 0)
              {
                  var t1 = FillDataSourceForElem(field);

                  listTasks.Add(t1);

                  if (kkey == lowLevelElementKey)
                  {
                      var t2 = Task.Run(async () =>
                       {
                           if (field.Level >= 1 && field.Level <= 8)
                           {
                               await FillAllChilds(field.Id);
                           }
                           else if (field.Level == 10)
                           {
                               await FillAppartments(field.Id);
                               await FillCarPlaces(field.Id);
                           }
                           else if (field.Level == 11)
                           {
                               await FillRooms(field.Id);
                           }
                       });
                      listTasks.Add(t2);
                  }
              }
          }
          Console.WriteLine("before when all");
          //stack here, but only in browser and only 1 time after start server. Working 
          //fine in MAUI Blazor
          await Task.WhenAll(listTasks.ToArray()).ConfigureAwait(false);
          Console.WriteLine("after when all");
          InvokeAsync(() => { StateHasChanged(); });
          //_ = Task.Run(async () =>
          // {
          //     await Task.WhenAll(listTasks.ToArray());
          //     await InvokeAsync(() => { StateHasChanged(); });

          // });

  }

await Task.WhenAll(listTasks.ToArray()) stuck every time when open page with this code, but only 1st time after start server. If i close browser page and reopen it code will not stuck and will working fine. Same code working fine in Blazor MAUI. i thought what it is dead lock, then add ConfigureAwait(false), but it did not help. If i fire and forget WhenAll like in comment it will work fine too, but i need block interface before operation will complete. In each function FillDataSourceForElem, FillAllChilds and etc just calling await _httpClient.GetAsync(). Server side work fine and return response fast.
If i remove Additional Task and WhenAll and try await each function (FillDataSourceForElem, FillAllChilds and etc) i will stuck on await _httpClient.GetAsync(), but every time i will stuck on different function. First time in FillDataSourceForElem, next time in FillAllChilds and etc.
Now i have no idea why it's happens.
Look like dead lock...
In F12 i see that browser did request, but did not get response (status wait). Then WhenAll stuck because tasks can't complete, but why it happens only 1 time and why it work in MAUI and why GetAsync stuck (if i do break point in server side in controller i see that controller method do return result).
If i fire and forget (like in comment) i see that all request did fast and get result from server and await WhenAll() in _ = Task.Run will complete fine.
if anyone knows the reason, I would be grateful.
I am using httpClient, what intitialize like this
     HttpClient _client;
     protected override async System.Threading.Tasks.Task  OnInitializedAsync()
     {
         _client = ClientFactory.CreateClient("clientName");
    
     }

Edit:
Full call stack:
In blazor component
 protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
 {
     await Initialise();
 }

then
 private async Task Initialise()
 {

     var result = await GetAddressFromDB();
 }

then
private async Task<bool> GetAddressFromDB()
 {
     try
     {
         var elem = await _client.GetFromJsonAsync<AddressElement>($"url?idForm={IdForm}");
         if (elem is null)
             return false;


             if (elem.Region is null)
                 return false;
             if (elem.Region.Id <= 0)
                 return false;

             address.UseMun = elem.UseMun;
             IsMunHierarchy = address.UseMun;

             await SelectNewAddress(elem, false);
             elem.RajonTown.Copy(address.RajonTown);
            
         return true;

     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         //log error
     }
     return false;
 }

---
 private async Task FillDataSourceForElem(AddressField elem)
   {

       List<AddressField> fields = new List<AddressField>();
       if (elem.Level >= 1 && elem.Level <= 8)
       {

           var rez = await SearchChildsElements(elem.IdParent);
           fields = rez.Where(p => p.Level == elem.Level).ToList();

       }
       else if (elem.Level == 9)
       {

           fields = await GetSteads(elem.IdParent);

       }
       else if (elem.Level == 10)
       {

           var rez = await GetHouses(elem.IdParent);
           fields = rez.Select(x => { AddressField b = x; return b; }).ToList();

       }
       else if (elem.Level == 11)
       {

           fields = await GetAppartments(elem.IdParent);

       }
       else if (elem.Level == 12)
       {

           fields = await GetRooms(elem.IdParent);

       }
       else if (elem.Level == 17)
       {

           fields = await GetCarPlaces(elem.IdParent);

       }


       foreach (var fieldChild in fields)
       {
           address.AddAddreesFieldInSameLevel(fieldChild);
       }

   }

  private async Task<List<AddressField>> SearchChildsElements(long idParent)
  {
      List<AddressField> result = null;
      try
      {
          result = await _client.GetFromJsonAsync<List<AddressField>>($"url?id={idParent}&useMun={_isMunHierarchy}");
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {

          //log here
      }
      if (result is null)
          return new List<AddressField>();

      return result;
  }

Answer
Don't use multi tasks in WASM. After disabled additional tasks freeze stopped. (Possible case for using Tasks https://www.meziantou.net/don-t-freeze-ui-while-executing-cpu-intensive-work-in-blazor-webassembly.htm)

Is this Blazor WASM? Because the WASM implementation doesn't support multithreading yet which could potentially be the problem.

@Jonathan, Yeap, It WASM.

Browsers only use a single thread per tab. You can't change that by starting multiple tasks. You can use a Service Worker to do some things in the background. The question's code is too complicated anyway but there doesn't seem to be any reason to use multiple tasks. Why use Task.Run for every item in a dictionary? What are those Fill methods doing that needs multiple threads?

@PanagiotisKanavos, i using Tasks for optimization. Fill methods do request to the server, get in response some items and fill datasource for autocomplete control (just add element in List). If i remove Tasks and WhenAll and write in foreach await FillDataSourceForElem(field); i will get block too.

This isn't optimization. On the contrary, it adds significant overhead as it tries to retrieve objects one by one. This is the slowest way possible, even in desktop applications that talk to DBs directly. It even has a name, Row By Agonizing Row. If you need multiple objects it's the server's job to construct a DTO with all the objects and return it. That's how GraphQL and OData work and why GraphQL is used in all SPA platforms. EF and all ORMs already return graphs of objects, and libraries like HotChocolate can map GraphQL queries to EF directly

Until you fix the server, remove Task.Run and listTasks and await the requests one by one. Look into patterns like MVVM or MVU too, as talking to the server is not the job of Razor components. The feature that performs work in the background is Web Workers, not service workers. These still use a single thread each, and communicate with the main thread using messages

@PanagiotisKanavos,
Let me explain what this task is. This is the address selection form. An address consists of address elements street, city, district, etc. When my form loads for the first time, I load the entire address, but I also need to request combobox elements for each address element, which is done in a loop. Of course, it would be possible to do all this in one request, but for now it’s done like this.

@PanagiotisKanavos, The question is why it freezes even when I remove tasks and wait one at a time in a loop. And even in the current implementation it freezes only when opened for the first time. After closing the tab and opening it again, everything works as expected. In the post I added implementations of the functions you asked about.

Pinpointed where the problem is probably impossible with the information provided.  However, the information that this only happens when you load the page first time points to the problem being in one of the scoped/singleton services you are using.  In WASM mode the single thread is almost certainly being blocked.  You need to look closely at each of those methods you're awaiting.  It would be interesting to know how many tasks you are awaiting?

@MrCakaShaunCurtis, I did another test. I launched another background task at the beginning of the method, and by removing it, the freezes stopped. Thanks everyone for your help. I really didn't know that WASM doesn't support multithreading and I can't use tasks.

There is a multi-threaded experimental version, but don't rush to it. There appear to be some show stopper issues with compatibility with .Net Core functionality that are probably yet to be solved.
